# How to let zsh replace a typed command in terminal with something I predefined?

Tags: git, jira, zsh, oh-my-zsh

So I want to use the jira [smart commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver072/processing-issues-with-smart-commits-829057223.html) but having to type the same things repetitively is annoying.

So I would like to have this behaviour in my command line (zsh) when typing:

```
git commit -m "|
```

should automatically be replaced with:

```
git commit -m "JIRPRJ-| #comment "
```

where `|`is the current cursor position. Does anyone know if there is already a plugin or snippet for it or how I can achieve this? I looked into the autocomplete functionality of zsh but it seemed to be not exactly what I want?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

1 - Global aliases

Global aliases are like this:

```
alias -g cc='xclip -selection clipboard'
```

Now you can do:

```
grep -i 'myuser$' /etc/passwd | cc
```

By the way cc is a mnemonic for clipboard copy

Another global alias:

```
alias -g NF='*(.om[1])'
```

Now you can list the newest file

```
ls NF
```

or edit it

```
vim NF
```

2 - Use a zsh addon called [zshnip](https://github.com/facetframer/zshnip)
The zshnip has "placeholders" you can use to fit your needs.

3 - Creat a zsh function (could be pasted on your ~/.zshrc)

```
gc () {
    echo "doing git commit -m "$1"
    git commit -m "$1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Thanks to you I found what I was searching for:
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/globalias 
It was listed on the reference page of zshnip!

I will post it as a separate answer but your post helped me find it!

Answer (score 0):

Found a cool Plugin thanks to  @SergioAraujo:

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/globalias

```
#Just had to add it to my zsh plugins:
plugins=(... globalias)

#and define a global alias for jira smart git commits
alias -g gcj="git commit -m \"JIRPROJ- #comment"
```

need to refine the the alias a little but works as intended! :)